# Redirect php error to error page along with error thrown

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2

I did some searching for this, but it's a little too generic to pull up results. I'm quite sure it can be done, but I can't find the right posts. Basically I am using CodeIgniter as my back end, and I throw exceptions from EVERYWHERE. When an exception happens, I want to throw the user to an error page BUT I also want to include the error message and stack trace so I can store it into my error table. The worst case scenario would be to put all my code into a try-catch loop, but that's ridiculous. Is there anything I can do with something like the .htaccess file? Remember, I need the exception to be passed along with the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [set_exception_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) and [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) functions, I think that's what you're looking for. Also at the [Error Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) session on the PHP Documentation.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. What's the difference between set_exception_handler and set_error_handler? I did come across set_exception_handler and someone was complaining that it wasn't catching all errors.

Comment: The function set on `set_exception_handler` will be called if a exception is thrown outside a try/catch block, if you catch the exception, the funciton will not be triggered, The function on `set_error_handler` will handle whatever error happen on the script, it'll not catch E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR and E_COMPILE_WARNING since when this errors happen your handler was not registered yet, and like the documentation said, most of E_STRICT will not be catch if it occurs on the same file where `set_error_handler` is being called.